# Exceptions: When handling is the same, one block or many?

Tags: php, exception

In situations where the error handling is the same (I echo the error and pass the `$_POST` data back to the form), is there any reason to split code into multiple try-catch blocks? I have a `get` command, which can fail if an invalid ID was passed; I have setters, which fail if the entry doesn't validate; and I have a `write`, which fails if it fails to write to the database or some late validation failed. Let's say that, on this page, all exceptions result in the same notice being displayed to the user (with help from `$e->getMessage()` of course). So does it seem better to go with...

```
// Try the whole block
try {
    $var = $manager->get($id);
    $var->setFoo('bar');
    $var->setShazbot('fnord');
    $manager->write($var);
}
catch (DataException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch (ValidationException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

or...

```
// Try getting
try {
    $var = $manager->get($id);
}
catch (DataException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Try setting
try { 
    $var->setFoo('bar');
    $var->setShazbot('fnord');
}
catch (ValidationException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Try committing
try {
    $manager->write($var);
}
catch (DataException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now, keep in mind, again, that in this example, *all three catch blocks are doing the same thing*. However, getting, validating, and writing are three distinct things, and I was thinking it might be more sane to try and catch them individually rather than all at once. What makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where it's really not about style. It's really all about what you want your code to do when an Exception is thrown.

Do the statements in the block depend on each other to work properly? Are they a logical grouping that need to stop if one call fails?

If so, then wrap them all in a single block and handle the Exceptions there.

If not (meaning the code can continue on to the next small block of statements without the previous call executing successfully), then go ahead and break them up.

Comment: Wow, duh, that makes perfect sense and I'm disappointed I didn't pick up on it. Of course I don't want to even try the `write()` (even though it should almost certainly fail) if previous validations fail.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are handling the exceptions in the same way, I'd group them into one block. This makes cleaner looking code and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have specific cleanup routines for each line then it's acceptable to catch all the exceptions at once. But never catch the top exception parent of course, since you may catch exceptions that you have no business handling.